# Flutter- How to redirect to specific activity when back button is pressed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to **redirect** my current flutter page to home page **when back button is pressed**. When i press back button the home page/activity should start. I have multiple selections in home page and in current page i am displaying eyes if user don't want to select they can press back to go to homepage.

here is code for my current page/activity

```
import '../DataFetching/face_part.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';




class EyesFetch extends StatelessWidget {


  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }

}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _DataFetching createState() => _DataFetching();
}

class _DataFetching extends State<MyHomePage>{
   Future<List<facial>> list =   facial.alleyes();
  List<facial> alleyes=new List<facial>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text("fetch"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

        new FutureBuilder<List<facial>>(
        future: list, // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<facial>> snapshot) {

            List<Widget> children;
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              var result=snapshot.data;
              for(var item in result)
              {
                alleyes.add(new facial(criminal_id: item.criminal_id,
                    part_size: item.part_size,
                    link: item.link));
              }
              children = <Widget>[

            new Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            child: getHomePageBody(context))

              ];
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              children = <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.error_outline,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  size: 60,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                  child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
                )
              ];
            } else {
              children = <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                ),

              ];
            }
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: children,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),


           ]// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    )));

  }

   getHomePageBody(BuildContext context) {
     final _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
     return Container(
         height: _screenSize.height * 0.85,
    child:
    new GridView.builder(
         scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
         shrinkWrap: true,
         itemCount: alleyes.length,
         gridDelegate:
         SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount (crossAxisCount: 3),

         itemBuilder: (context,index){
           return _getItemUI(context,index);
         }));
   }
   Widget _getItemUI(BuildContext context, int index) {

     return Container(

       child: Card(

         child:

           new Image.network(alleyes[index].link, fit: BoxFit.cover),



       ),


     );
   }


}
```

so what could i use here so that the back pressing functionality can be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle a back pressed event in the Flutter with help of [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) widget. and you will find `onWillPop` method

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
    child: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          "On Back pressed",
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text("Home Page"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Implement _onBackPressed Method with what you want to do on back press:

```
Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
  return ANYTHING YOU WANT TO DO ??
      false;
}
```

[CHECK OUT THIS BLOG FOR MORE DETAIL](https://medium.com/@iamatul_k/flutter-handle-back-button-in-a-flutter-application-override-back-arrow-button-in-app-bar-d17e0a3d41f)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WillPopScope` to achieve this.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: ()  {
       // your logic here
   },
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Home Page"),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text("Home Page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```